# Refresh page during ajax call is destroying the php session

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

When I do an AJAX call, I need to wait its response to show it to the user.

```
function update() {
    if (HttpReq.readyState == 4) {
        if (HttpReq.status == 200) {
            var div = document.getElementById('divAjax');
            div.innerHTML = HttpReq.responseText;
        } else {
            alert("Error: " + HttpReq.statusText);
        }
    }
}

HttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
HttpReq.onreadystatechange = update;
HttpReq.open('GET', 'some_url.php', true);
HttpReq.send(null);
```

However, if the user presses F5 to refresh the screen before that response, I lose my $_SESSION data, what automatically logs the user out.

Is this a common behavior, or is there a problem with my code? (I'm using a secure session loader, maybe the problem is there. I can post the code if needed.)

The problem is not exactly with the F5, it's something that's happening in some special circumstances, that's just the simplest way I've found to reproduce the behavior.

Code:

```
// index.php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
session_save_path('/var/www/html/plantas/sessions');
sec_session_start(); // this line called in every other .php file

// functions.php
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../html/plantas/error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"],
        $cookieParams["domain"],
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);

    session_start();                // Start the PHP session
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}

// every other .php file begin with
include_once '../../includes/db_connect.php';
include_once '../../includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
```

SOLUTION

to cut

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

from functions.php and insert it after

```
// index.php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
session_save_path('/var/www/html/plantas/sessions');
sec_session_start(); // this line called in every other .php file
```

Comment: yes, better show all the code involved.

Comment: some_url.php check what is inside this request

Comment: in normal scenario session is closed only when you close browser, unless you have checks involved for back button and refresh, which does not seems to be case with you. so yeah ,sharing involved code will help.

Comment: Added some code. @YehiaAwad, I have a few dozens of php files, any of them may give a similar error.

Comment: @akmsharma Actually, I have no code for back button or refresh.

Comment: What happens if you don't regenerate_session_id when it is an Ajax call?

Comment: @CWürtz, looks like that solved the problem! :)

Comment: XSS vulnerability in error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_regenerate_id()` means the session is renamed each time an URL is called by a full page load or an Ajax request. 
But the session cookie is not overridden during an Ajax request due to `http_only=true`. 
And because `session_regenerate_id(true)` delete the old session, if between two full page load there is an Ajax call, the session identifier is lost by the client.

You should not use `session_regenerate_id($anything)` during an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code, you have this line code `session_regenerate_id(true);` which is doing exactly what you don't want, but why ?

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php):

> session_regenerate_id() will replace the current session id with a new
>   one, and keep the current session information.

but that shouldn't delete your old session, so what is happening?
In fact you are setting the `bool` parameter to `true` (default is `false`) which is telling the preprocessor to delete the old session an replace it with a new one

> bool session_regenerate_id ([ bool $delete_old_session = false ] )

so to solution to your problem is to remove the `true` parameter inside the native method and keep it simply like that : `session_regenerate_id();`

EDIT

If this request is only used in Ajax then starting or working with session is redundant. Unless you are checking user Authentity before making the request.

Comment: In this case a single user has several sessions. It sounds not like Rodrigo wants. It seems he want very securize his traces.

Comment: @CWürtz If he is using the regenerate session it means he needs it for some purpose maybe this function is used in another place where it is not ajax it depends on the architecture of his code moreover to be more specific if it is only ajax then he shouldn't use session at all function and delete what is rest in the code )

Comment: Yeap. In this case, he sould read how use a session token (client site & server side).

Comment: Session token is used for csrf protection and for keeping a specific session until it reaches a desired target I don't see any use of these both for ajax